# Images will not display, when I call them up with html in wordpress, just two blank small spaces

Tags: images, html

I am trying to get images to display, when I call it up with html in wordpress. I am using html instead of the image block in wordpress, as I want to animate the images a bit.
I also uploaded the images in the media library.
I just get two small blank spaces, but no actual image.
I have tried the following:

```html
<div id="fading">
    <img class="bottom" src="Ankleboots.jpg"><br>
    <img class="top" src="Belts.jpg">
</div>
```

and have also tried the following:

```html
<img class="bottom" src="Pictures/leatherproducts/Ankleboots.jpg">
<div id="fading">
    <img class="top" src="Pictures/leatherproducts/Belts.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: those are relative URLs not absolute URLs, the browser will look in different places for them on different pages. This isn't a WordPress problem, this is a HTML fundamentals problem

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: also, you don't need custom HTML to add animations, add a custom CSS class to a group block or the image block using the advanced panel, and you can use that to target your CSS, custom HTML is completely unnecessary. ( you also fell into a common trap, the X Y problem, where you asked how to fix your solution, not how to solve your problem. You should have asked how to animate 2 image blocks, not how to fix your attempt )

Comment: Images added to the media library typically live at /wp-content/uploads/[year]/[month] (but in the WP Admin at Settings > Media you can enable/disable the year/month folder groupings.